# can't set up fail2ban Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, fail2ban

I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fail2ban
sudo cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

With out activating any jails or anything else:

```
sudo systemctl restart fail2ban

Job for fail2ban.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. See "systemctl status fail2ban.service" and "journalctl -xe" for 
details.

sudo service fail2ban status
● fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-01-01 15:04:10 
UTC; 24s ago
Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
Process: 9828 ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 14906 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, 
status=255)
Main PID: 647 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Jan 01 15:04:10 benja2 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Control process exited, 
code=exited status=255
Jan 01 15:04:10 benja2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Jan 01 15:04:10 benja2 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed 
state.
Jan 01 15:04:10 benja2 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 
'exit-code'.
Jan 01 15:04:10 benja2 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Service hold-off time 
over, scheduling restart.
Jan 01 15:04:10 benja2 systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
Jan 01 15:04:10 benja2 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Start request repeated 
too quickly.
Jan 01 15:04:10 benja2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
```

How do I set up fail2ban so it can start?

Comment: What does the output for the command ' journalctl -xe' show? Normally there is more information about the issue in this output.

Comment: Fail2ban is up and running, thanks for helping.  apt-get -f install to force an install did it. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-a-171107/